# Centering a Div element with multiple different elements and classes inside

Tags: html, css, centering

I have been attempting to make a HTML-based email for a class I'm in. I have gotten to the footer where I would like a box at the bottom with a "legal disclaimer" and clickable links. I have gotten the box and all of the content inside of it, but I have been unable to center it (I have tried using `text-align:center;`)*

Heres a snippet of code from that section HTML and CSS included *edited to exclude personal information*

HTML:

```
<div>
  <p class="footnote">Legal disclaimer here</p>
    <p class="footnote">Please do not reply to this email.</p>
<a class="footnote" href="link" alt="broken link">link 1</a> 
<a class="footnote" href="link" alt="broken link">link 2</a> 
<a class="footnote" href="link" alt="broken link">link 3</a> 
<a class="footnote" href="link" alt="broken link">link 4</a>
  </div>
```

<--note the div shown here has its own class but I removed it for this example-->

CSS:

```
.div{
  background-color: #f4f5f5;
  border: none;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
.footnote{
  font-size: 11px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of what you're trying to achieve, but if you want something like this

[image]

just center the container adding margin `auto` on its horizontal sides.

This is the code:

```css
.centered {
    background-color: #f4f5f5;
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 16px auto 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.footnote {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div>Content and stuff preceding footer...</div>

    <div class="centered">
        <p class="footnote">Legal disclaimer here</p>
        <p class="footnote">Please do not reply to this email.</p>
        <a class="footnote" href="link" alt="broken link">link 1</a>
        |
        <a class="footnote" href="link" alt="broken link">link 2</a>
        |
        <a class="footnote" href="link" alt="broken link">link 3</a>
        |
        <a class="footnote" href="link" alt="broken link">link 4</a>
    </div>
</div>
```